# PyCharm weird Type warning

Tags: python, pycharm

Why does the following code:

```
v = [None for _ in range(3)]
v[-1] = 0                       <<<
```

tell me this?

Unexpected type(s):
(int, int)
Possible types:
(int, None)
(slice, Iterable[None])
...

Comment: Looks like a warning from PyCharm, right?

Comment: @sanyash correct :)

Comment: It seems that PyCharm does not like the fact that you sometimes have `None` in the list and somtimes `int`. And I agree with PyCharm. There is hardly a good  reason to ever do `v = [None for _ in range(3)]`.

Comment: I don't agree with PyCharm. It is not specified that v is a list only of Nones, so there is no error in assigning an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Lists are mutable sequences, **typically used to store collections of homogeneous items** (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by application).

*int* and *NoneType* are not considered homogeneous (by *PyCharm*'s code inspections), hence the warning. The simplest way to get around it, is to populate the list with *int*s:

```py
v = [0 for _ in range(3)]  # [0] * 3  # Shorter
v[-1] = 0
```

As an alternative, you can use tuples as heterogeneous items containers (as @Jeyekomon pointed out), but bear in mind that **a tuple is immutable** (once created, it can't be altered).

Comment: Also if anyone now wonders what structure is then recommended to store collections of heterogeneous data, it is [Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples).

Answer (score 6):

A simple workaround to get rid of such warning is to put a type hint on `v` variable:

```
v: list = [None for i in range(3)]
v[-1] = 0
```

PyCharm will treat it as `v: list[Any]` and allow you to assign a value of any type without warnings.